# What kind of Den can I use to design a fair fight against the post-Vault Dragons?

Tags: dnd-4e, encounter-design, dragons

So, everybody knows the Dragons are Stronger since Monster's Vault came out.

My question is simple.
What kind of geographic solution can I use to make my group have a fair fight against a Dragon without seeming to be pushing too hard?

I need the place to give some mobility to the Dragon to do it's thing but not enough to abuse some combat styles that can be used by dragons (as Breath Weapon abuse, ranged attacks or even grab-and-drop). But the places need to make sense as in "Why would the Dragon be there?" besides "There is where its treasure is".

Answer (score 2):

**Where to fight**

Anything with a roof will severely hamper the dragon's mobility. Traditionally that means a cave of some kind, but don't rule out large magically-built structures. From a realism perspective it's important to remember that not only does the chamber have to be big enough for the fight, it should have an entrance/exit big enough for the dragon to have reasonably passed through, though theoretically a really big teleportation circle would also work.

The other alternative to a roof is strong columns relatively closely spaced. The columns could be artificial, but a cluster of small mesas would also work. A redwood forest would also be a strong contender. The dragon would have room to land and take off, albeit with a fair amount of difficulty, but strafing would be out of the question.

**Why to fight there**

Obviously the traditional answer is to protect its hoard, but you seem to be looking for some alternatives to that so I'll toss out a few suggestions.

Any kind of node or ley line that generates power, especially power of the type appropriate to the dragon (fire for a red dragon, ice for a white dragon, etc.) will be both very attractive to dragons and something they can't just carry off. The dragon might be capable of drawing power from the site itself, either passively but very slowly (basically letting it increase in size/age faster than normal, and therefore providing no benefit during the fight) or possibly in a more immediate fashion that requires the dragon to channel it, sometimes using its actions to absorb or direct the energy during the fight. Alternately the dragon may be incapable of using the power source itself and instead be motivated by a desire to deny others the use of that power, especially if that power is of an opposing element or somehow capable of being used against the dragon. Better to fight in a cave than let someone power up a legendary artifact of dragonslaying.

The dragon may also just need to be at the location in question at a specific time. Maybe it's meeting some other powerful creature there (a demon? a lich?) for the D&D equivalent of a drug deal, bartering evil goods and/or services. Or perhaps the dragon's current scheme requires a ritual performed at a suitable site at a specific time; it may not be the dragon's ideal venue for fighting some adventurers, but if the alternative is waiting another 200 years for the next astral conjunction...

Maybe the dragon *has* to be there. Dragons are certainly BAMFs, but there are other entities out there that are as strong or stronger. The dragon may have been ordered or compelled to guard a specific spot. It may be cursed to spend one night there every cycle of the moon.

---

**A digression on grab-and-drop**

Under the 4e rules, moving a grabbed target requires a *standard* action and a strength check vs the target's fortitude, and limits the grabber to half their speed. The dragon won't inflict much damage with grab & drop if it's burning its standard action every round just to deal (speed/4 - 2)d10 damage to one character. Plus, because moving the grabbed target is explicitly a pull, and therefore subject to the rules of forced movement, there are two further complications:

1. Per p212-213 of the Rules Compendium, if a target is forced "over a precipice... the target can immediately make a saving throw to avoid going over the edge... If the creature saves, it falls prone in the last square it occupied before it would have fallen..." Being carried into the air pretty clearly qualifies, so characters are automatically entitled to a save over & beyond any escape attempts to break free when the dragon tries to lift them.
2. Per p213 of the Rules Compendium, "Forced movement is normally two-dimensional; all the squares of the movement must be on the same horizontal plane. ... This means an earthbound target cannot normally be pushed to a square in the air." Unless the dragon has a power that explicitly allows vertical pulls, the PCs can't be lifted, period.

DMs are, of course, entitled to create their own exceptions to these rules. I would *strongly* recommend caution regarding creating precedents regarding vertical forced movement, however. There are number of powers available to characters that become absurdly overpowered if their forced movement can be used to lift & drop targets (or even just force them to save or fall prone), and I'm wanting to say we have questions *on this site* about how to deal with the resulting arms race between the party & the DM in their attempts to launch each other into the stratosphere. The rules of 4e don't exist to simulate reality, they exist to support balanced tactical combat; if you find yourself bending them "because that's what would happen" with any regularity, then 4e may not be the best system for you.